# Oracle SQL : Getting the first row with filters

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I get the first row filtering some values out? I used row_number() over(partition by Name ORDER BY Date) to get the order (See example below). But I need, the rank will start at the last occurrence of Type = B (See expected output)

```
SELECT Name, Age, Type, Date, 
       row_number() over(partition by Name ORDER BY Date) as Rank
FROM TableA;
```

For example :

```
Name   Age   Type   Date          Rank
Ben    12      A    2013/02/01    1 
Rod    14      A    2013/02/05    2
Zed    13      B    2013/03/09    3
Ken    12      A    2013/04/02    4 
Jed    14      B    2013/05/01    5
Mar    13      A    2013/05/04    6
Nic    12      A    2013/06/02    7
Jen    15      A    2013/06/09    8
```

Expected Output :

```
Name   Age    Type   Date         Rank
Mar    13      A    2013/05/04    1
Nic    12      A    2013/06/02    2
Jen    15      A    2013/06/09    3
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
WITH qry AS 
(
  SELECT "Name", "Age", "Type", "Date", 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "Type" ORDER BY "Date") rank
  FROM TableA
)
SELECT "Name", "Age", "Type", "Date"
  FROM qry
 WHERE rank = 1
```

Output:

```
| NAME | AGE | TYPE |                            DATE |
-------------------------------------------------------
|  Ben |  12 |    A | February, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
|  Zed |  13 |    B |    March, 09 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/70971/7)** demo

Comment: This selects the highest ranked A and B. I read the question as "I need all records newer than the newest B".

Comment: @MartinSchapendonk OP changed the question.

Answer (score 2):

There is another possibility: You could wrap it in a subquery:

```
select
    t.*
  from
    (SELECT "Name", "Age", "Type", "Date", 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "Type" ORDER BY "Date") rank
       FROM TableA
     ) t
  where
    rank = 1
```

"Sub queries" and "*common table expressions* (`with`)" behave differently, so have a look at these approaches. It depends on your case, if one is mandatory (dealing with side-effects) or one is faster. In case of [Oracle](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_with_clause.htm), there is even a `materialize` hint. "Per SQL standard, CTEs offer an optimization fence feature" (this is an adapted quote from [here](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/5073F810.5060703@ringerc.id.au)).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Name, Age, Type, Date, 
       row_number() over(partition by Name ORDER BY Date) as Rank
FROM TableA
WHERE type <> 'B'
AND Date > (
    SELECT max(Date)
    FROM TableA
    WHERE type = 'B'
);
```

Please note that this assumes that there are no A's on the exact same date/time as the last B.

Answer (score 0):

this should also do what you asked for:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over(partition by "Name" ORDER BY "Date") as Rank
from  TableA t
where "Date" >= (select max("Date") from TableA where "Type" = 'B')
```